# Custom swift camera circle touch response

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, camera

I am trying to add a circle to my custom camera view.I have a problem to center it to my "touch point", because it adds my circle to the top left corner when I touch the screen, but when I replace "centerPoint" next to arcCenter with some CGPoint(//Some constrains) in the second line of code it adds my point to the right CGPoint.

This is my code so far:

```
func pointInCamera(centerPoint:CGPoint){


        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: CGFloat(30), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)//This "centerPoint" is the problem I guess             
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath

        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 0.3).CGColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 191/255, blue: 1, alpha: 0.9).CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0

        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    }

    //Focus camera

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        let screenSize = cameraView.bounds.size
        if let touchPoint = touches.first {
            let x = touchPoint.locationInView(cameraView).y / screenSize.height
            let y = 1.0 - touchPoint.locationInView(cameraView).x / screenSize.width
            let focusPoint = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

            let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

            if let device = backCamera {
                do {
                    try device.lockForConfiguration()
                    device.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint

                    pointInCamera(focusPoint)
                    device.focusMode = .AutoFocus
                    device.exposurePointOfInterest = focusPoint
                    device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.ContinuousAutoExposure
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()


                }
                catch {
                    // just ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that touches on the siri remote are relative instead of absolute touches on an ios device. So i think the touch location (0/0) is at the currently focused view.

Comment: Yes, it is true that it prints that my touch location is 0/0 , but how can I make it right?

Comment: I dont understand what you want to do. A screenshot would be helpful. I think the problem is in the line where you calculate x and y: Why do you divide by the screensize? locationInView() should return the correct CGPoint where the touch happened

Comment: pointInCamera(touchPoint.locationInView(cameraView)) worked thanks @matthiaswitt ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Created this function und added it to my touchesBegan function:

```
func pointInCamera(centerPoint:CGPoint){

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: CGFloat(30), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath

        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 0.3).CGColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 191/255, blue: 1, alpha: 0.9).CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0

        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        delay(0.5) { 
            shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }

    }
```